# Using Primary auxiliary "did" with two verbs using "and"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Please consider these two sentences:

> (a)  Did the train arrive at 11:00 **and** **departed** at 11:15?
>
> vs
>
> (b)  Did the train arrive at 11:00 **and depart** at 11:15?

Another sentence:

> (a) Did you go to market **and bought** groceries?
>
> vs
>
> (b) Did you go to market **and buy** groceries?

Which  sentences in set 1 and set 2 are correct?

I have been told to use 1st form of any verb after **did** (primary auxiliary) but I get puzzled when I use another verb after **and**.

In a past question made with the
primary auxiliary "did", should I use the 2nd form of the verb depart which is **departed**, or 1st form of the verb depart (in set 1)?

and 2nd form of verb buy which is bought or 1st form buy? (in set 2)

I would really appreciate your help, guys.

Comment: Always use an infinitive verb-form (your 1st form) after the auxiliary "do", even in a coordination of verb phrases linked by "and". Thus "depart" and "buy" are the correct verbs in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

"B" is correct in both examples. When using the auxiliary *did*, the verbs that follow should always be in the infinitive, even if they're separated by *and*. Since *did* is in the past tense, the following verbs cannot also be. *Did bought* and *did departed* don't make sense and are incorrect.

In the absence of *did*, and in the form of a statement rather than a question, the other verbs should be in the past:

- *The train **arrived** at 11:00 and **departed** at 11:15.*
- *You **went** to the market and **bought** groceries.*

Comment: Verbs that follow auxiliary "do" are plain (infinitival) forms. Thus, "depart" and "buy" are not present tense, but plain (infinitival) forms.

Comment: Good catch; I corrected it.